# How to get least(min) value from array of object?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, underscore.js

I have a an array that contains list of json object like mentioned below:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "type":"type1",
        "selling_price":2199,
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "type":"type1",
        "selling_price":4999,
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "type":"type1",
        "selling_price":6999,
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "type":"type2",
        "selling_price":1999,
    },
    {
        "id":5,
        "type":"type2",
        "selling_price":2399,
    },
    {
        "id":6,
        "type":"type2",
        "selling_price":2999,
    }
]
```

I want to extract min selling price for only type="type1". the min price should be 2199 for type1
I tried using below method but its not working

```
_.map(arr, price => {
    if(price.type=="type1") {
        let pp =_.min(price, function(minPrice){ return minPrice.selling_price; });
        console.log(pp)
    }
});
```

Edit code suggested by @VLAZ

```
data() {
    return {
        minSellingPrice:'',
        arr:[]
    }
},
method() {
    leastPrice() {
        if(this.arr) {
            const result = _.chain(arr)
              .filter(item => item.type === "type1")
              .map('selling_price')
              .min()
              .value()
            this.minSellingPrice=result;
        }       
        else this.minSellingPrice=''
    }
}
```

by default the this.minSellingPrice should be empty but with this code whenever this.minSellingPrice is showing as infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the mapping wrong. You have the condition inside the callback which only gives you one item at a time. Instead, you should [`filter()`](https://underscorejs.org/#filter) the collection to only the type you want first, then get the [`min()`](https://underscorejs.org/#min) price.

Underscore has the [`_.chain()` method](https://underscorejs.org/#chaining) which allows you to do multiple operations on the same dataset without needing to save intermediate results. To get the result at the end, you need to call `.value()` to signify no further calls would be chained:

```js
const arr = [ { "id":1, "type":"type1", "selling_price":2199, }, { "id":2, "type":"type1", "selling_price":4999, }, { "id":3, "type":"type1", "selling_price":6999, }, { "id":4, "type":"type2", "selling_price":1999, }, { "id":5, "type":"type2", "selling_price":2399, }, { "id":6, "type":"type2", "selling_price":2999, } ];

const result = _.chain(arr)
  .filter(item => item.type === "type1")
  .min('selling_price')
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.11.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

If you want just the price, not the object itself, you can use [`map()`](https://underscorejs.org/#map) to extract just that property:

```js
const arr = [ { "id":1, "type":"type1", "selling_price":2199, }, { "id":2, "type":"type1", "selling_price":4999, }, { "id":3, "type":"type1", "selling_price":6999, }, { "id":4, "type":"type2", "selling_price":1999, }, { "id":5, "type":"type2", "selling_price":2399, }, { "id":6, "type":"type2", "selling_price":2999, } ];

const result = _.chain(arr)
  .filter(item => item.type === "type1")
  .map('selling_price')
  .min()
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.11.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

If you want a fallback value in case of an empty array, currently the code will return `Infinity`, since this is the default return of `min`. Unfortunately, Underscore doesn't have a comprehensive enough API to easily solve it. One easy way is to just check for that value and substitute it with another for example.

```
if (result === Infinity) {
    result = null;
}
```

An alternative if you want to use only Undescore is to define your own method via [`mixin()`](https://underscorejs.org/#mixin). Many methods might solve the issue here but as a general helper method, I'd go for `or()` which will allow you to swap a value with another:

```js
/**
 * Generic function that either value or if the value fails a test a fallback
 * @param {*} value - value to be tested or substituted
 * @param {*} otherValue - fallback in case `value` fails the test
 * @param {Function} [test] - what the value would be tested against. By default it fails for null or undefined
 */
_.mixin({
  or: function(value, otherValue, test = x => x != null ) {
    return test(value) ? value : otherValue ;
  }
});

const fullArray = [ { "id":1, "type":"type1", "selling_price":2199, }, { "id":2, "type":"type1", "selling_price":4999, }, { "id":3, "type":"type1", "selling_price":6999, }, { "id":4, "type":"type2", "selling_price":1999, }, { "id":5, "type":"type2", "selling_price":2399, }, { "id":6, "type":"type2", "selling_price":2999, } ];

const emptyArray = [];


function getMinimum(arr) {
  return _.chain(arr)
    .filter(item => item.type === "type1")
    .map('selling_price')
    .min()
    .or("", _.isFinite) //use the or() mixin and pass a different test function that rejects `Infinity`
    .value();
}
  
const fullResult = getMinimum(fullArray);
const emptyResult = getMinimum(emptyArray);

console.log(`fullResult is [${fullResult}]`);
console.log(`emptyResult is [${emptyResult}]`); //empty string
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.11.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Lastly, if you like Underscore but find the API a bit limiting, like in this case, I'd suggest switching to [Lodash](https://lodash.com/). It is *very* close to Undescore as it splintered off at some point in the past. Lodash has a bit more consistent interface and a lot more functionality, so it a lot of cases it's a straight upgrade over Underscore or at least on par. The functionality you want expressed in Lodash is this:

```js
const fullArray = [ { "id":1, "type":"type1", "selling_price":2199, }, { "id":2, "type":"type1", "selling_price":4999, }, { "id":3, "type":"type1", "selling_price":6999, }, { "id":4, "type":"type2", "selling_price":1999, }, { "id":5, "type":"type2", "selling_price":2399, }, { "id":6, "type":"type2", "selling_price":2999, } ];

const emptyArray = [];


function getMinimum(arr) {
  return _.chain(arr) //no need for .chain() as Lodash implicitly chains via this
  .filter(item => item.type === "type1")
  .map('selling_price')
  .min() //min defaults to `undefined` if nothing is found
  .defaultTo(''); // similar to the `or()` mixin above but only for `undefined`, `null`, or `NaN`
  .value()
}
  
const fullResult = getMinimum(fullArray);
const emptyResult = getMinimum(emptyArray);

console.log(`fullResult is [${fullResult}]`);
console.log(`emptyResult is [${emptyResult}]`); //empty string
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Lodash supports everything needed out of the box to complete the entire operation, unlike Underscore.

Comment: but if arr is empty than it return infinity as result  @VLAZ

Comment: @Anji what result do you expect in that case?

Comment: if this.arr is empty then by default this.minSellingPrice should also be empty, but right now with your mentioned code it is gving infinity as result

Comment: I have edited the question with along with the solution using your code.

Comment: With the second snippet, the code will always return a scalar value, in this case a number. So, what would "empty" be in this case? `null`? `undefined`? I'll provide a solution that allows you to specify a fallback since it's currently not clear what value you expect

Comment: if  arr is empty then minSellingPrice=' '

Answer (score 0):

You use the function [minBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#maxBy) and filter function of lodash

```
let filter_arr = _.filter(arr, function(o) { return o.type=='type1';})
_.minBy(filter_arr,function(o) { 
  return o.selling_price; 
 });
```

It will give as below result

```
{id: 1, selling_price: 2199, type: "type1"}
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Why would it return `6999`? It's definitely not the minimum price. And there is no filtering for the type, either.